# Microsoft.OneDrive.Sdk PutAsync method not working properly

Tags: c#, onedrive

I'm trying to save a file in one drive from my Asp.NET mvc application. I succesfully log in but when I try to put a stream file with this method:

```
  var uploadedItem = await service.Drive.Root.ItemWithPath(uploadPath)
    .Content.Request().PutAsync<Item>(str);
```

the file is uploaded but when I download it, it's empty, 0 bytes. I'm stuck!

All help is welcome, Thanks!

Update:

The thing is that I'm getting the stream file from an `HttpPostedFileBase` file, it was working correctly until last week. I didn't modify anything there and this week the problem began.

I temporaly fixed it saving this file to a local folder on the solution and:

```
        private System.IO.Stream GetFileStreamForUpload(string tempFilePath)
        {
            try
            {
                return new System.IO.FileStream(tempFilePath, System.IO.FileMode.Open);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
...

var fileStream = GetFileStreamForUpload(filePath);

var uploadedItem = await service.Drive.Root.ItemWithPath(uploadPath)
.Content.Request().PutAsync<Item>(fileStream);
```

But I don't really like this solution.

Comment: Can you update your sample to show how you're getting `str`?

Comment: I have updated my sample. Tks!!!